# How do I return results of a date range of >=2 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to only pull records that have have a date span of 2 or more days.  I have over 8K records I need to search through.  What's the best way to do this please?  I'm using SQL Server 2014.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/011e4/1/0/)

In case SQL Fiddle doesn't work: (I've had issues getting it to work lately.)

```
create table #DD
    (
     Event varchar(100),
     ResponseBegin date,
     ResponseEnd date
    )

insert  into #DD
        (Event, ResponseBegin, ResponseEnd)
values  ('Det', '20150201', '20150202'),
        ('Adm', '20160201', '20160204'),
        ('MM', '20120201', '20120205'),
        ('Det', '20160201', '20160207'),
        ('Det', '20160201', '20160201')
```

Data

[image]

Desired Results

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Your sql-fiddle is empty

Comment: Thanks!  I added the code to the question.  I've had issues with it working lately.  I can see the schema is built and my select all query is showing as well.  Here's the link I can see it on.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/011e4/1/0

Comment: DATEDIFF(day,ResponseBegin,ResponseEnd) >= 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM DD WHERE DateAdd(DAY, 2, ResponseBegin) <= ResponseEnd
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan!  This nailed it!

Comment: Glad it worked. Just remember to mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM DD WHERE 
ResponseEnd <= DATEADD(day, 2, ResponseBegin)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

`SELECT * FROM DD WHERE ResponseEnd <= DATEADD(day, 2, ResponseBegin)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select *from #DD where DATEDIFF(D,ResponseBegin,ResponseEnd)>=2
```